# javascript timer and html progress bar to replace html

Tags: javascript, html

hi guys have a simple javascript countdown timer and a html progress bar on an html page.

I cant figure out how to get the script to replace the html page with a different one only after the progress bar has completed.

It either replaces the page nearly immediately or not at all or the progress wont move based on the different things I have tried can someone help me...here is the current code.

```js
var timeleft = 10;

var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById("progressBar").value = 10 - --timeleft;
  if (timeleft <= 0)
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
}, 1000);

if (document.getElementById("progressBar").value > 10) {
  window.location.replace('download.html');
}
```

```html
<center><progress value="0" max="10" id="progressBar" style="margin-top: -29px; height: 10px;"></progress></center>
```

Comment: It looks like your code causes the output to look like it is counting up. Do you have a default value set on the progressBar element that might be causing it to be > 10 after the first check?

Comment: all the code you see there is all the code there is for it...it counts  down 10 seconds I think but moves progress bar up..any better suggestion? fyi I tried > 10 still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if(document.getElementById("progressBar").value > 10){...}` isn't within your interval meaning it only runs once, right after the interval is created.

Additionally, `document.getElementById("progressBar").value` will never reach a value of greater than `10`.  It reaches `10` exactly but your interval has been told to stop.

Consider this:

```js
const progressEl = document.getElementById("progressBar");

let downloadTimer = setInterval(() => {
  progressEl.value++;

  if (progressEl.value >= progressEl.max) {
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    console.log("Would replace");
  }
}, 200);
```

```html
<progress value="0" max="10" id="progressBar"></progress>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you are looking for is code to be executed after the progress bar is complete, here is the solution:

```css
.hide{
  display: none;
}

.show{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<center><progress value="0" max="10" id="progressBar" style="margin-top: -29px; height: 10px;"></progress>
<div id="completed-alert" class="hide">Completed!!!</div></center>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var timeleft = 10;
  var progressBar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
  var alertBox = document.getElementById("completed-alert");
  var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
    if(timeleft <= 0)
      clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    progressBar.value = 10 - --timeleft;
    if(progressBar.value === 10){
      //window.location.replace('download.html');
      alertBox.classList.remove('hide');
      alertBox.classList.add('show');
    }
  }, 1000);
</script>
```